# Maven ignores @WebServlet annotation

Tags: servlets, maven, mapping

I had a Dynamic Web project which had a few @WebServlet annotations, all of which worked fine. I have since switched my Dynamic Web project to a Maven web project. Since doing so, I can't access any of my servlets by what I defined in my @WebServlet annotations. I should also note that some of my servlets are overlay from other Maven projects. Do I have to now define my servlet mappings in the web.xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maven story aside, the `@WebServlet` annotation was introduced in Servlet 3.0. If they are not initialized, then it simply means that either the web application descriptor (the `web.xml`) is not declared conform Servlet 3.0 or that the target container does not support Servlet 3.0.

You need to verify if your `web.xml` conforms Servlet 3.0. I.e., the `<web-app>` root declaration must match that:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

Comment: It would help if you're more specific in describing the problem. I am not immediately able to fly/beam over and come along you in person to take a peek in your environment to figure what error messages you got and what happens instead.

Comment: It was chocking up on my <servlet><description>....</description></servlet>... if I remove the description tag, it likes it just fine. I think that might be part of the DTD for 3.0. There was NO error message to provide you with, other than syntax in XML not correct. Also, that wasn't a maven error, I think it was just standard xml being checked agaisnt the schema provided. Thanks for your help, will mark as resolved.